# Using a cursor to return rows from SQLite, error when database is empty

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When my database is empty, or it has just been created I am getting this error,

> 03-10 17:34:40.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.adressbooktake2/com.example.adressbooktake2.MainActivity}:
>   android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Here is my code in my main class,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DBAdaptor db;   
    Cursor cursor;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        db = new DBAdaptor(this).open();        
        cursor = db.getAllRecords();

        DisplayRecord(cursor);

}
```

which then calls this code in my DBAdaptor class,

```
    public Cursor getAllRecords() 

    {       
        Cursor gaRecords = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
                        KEY_PHONENUMBER, KEY_EMAIL}, null, null, null, null, null);     


        gaRecords.moveToFirst();

        return gaRecords;

    }

}
```

I believe the problem is that when the database has just been created, there is nowhere for the moveToFirst() to go, as there is no data. But I am not sure how to get round this as I need a moveToFirst() for when there is a stocked database.

Anyone see a solution? Have a diagnosed the problem correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for an empty Cursor like this:

```
...
cursor = db.getAllRecords();
if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
    DisplayRecords(cursor);
else
    DisplayNoRecordsMessage();
```

Or since you posted `DisplayRecords()` in a previous question, you can also use:

```
...
if (c != null && !cursor.isAfterLast())
{
    nameTxt.setText(c.getString(1));
    phoneTxt.setText(c.getString(2));
    emailTxt.setText(c.getString(3));
}
```

Also please read about [Java naming convention](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) which states that method names should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: That sorted it! But I don't really understand why. Is it because it is only passing on the cursor if it is greater than 0? What happens to it when it is 0? Is it just forgotten about?

Comment: @user2153547 Exactly, when `getCount() == 0` your code won't call `DisplayRecords()`, when there are rows they will be displayed one by one.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK The author only wants to display one record at a time, I know this from a previous question. :) (This is why I didn't use `moveToFirst()`.)

Answer (score 0):

Cursor.moveToFirst() returns false in case of empty cursor.

See the doc: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29)

I'd say the problem is in DisplayRecord().

Are you fetching data from the cursor in DisplayRecord() ? If so, inside of it you should check if the cursor contains some data, calling *moveToFirst* and checking its result for example.

Something like

```
private void DisplayRecord(Cursor c){
    if(!c.moveToFirst()){
         return;
    }
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if(cursor .moveToFirst()) to check cursor

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DBAdaptor db;   
    Cursor cursor;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        db = new DBAdaptor(this).open();        
        cursor = db.getAllRecords();

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
           DisplayRecord(cursor);
            }


}
```